# AVG, MIN, MAX error in Pig while COUNT works

Tags: count, max, apache-pig, average, min

I'm trying to use AVG,MIN,MAX in Pig. Both MIN and MAX functions got stuck while executing and AVG function throws an error. But the COUNT function works fine.

> org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (GRADE 2 TEACHER,{(65587.90)}), 2nd :(GRADE 4 TEACHER,{(56567.24)})

My code:

```
register 'pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar';
define Replace org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE();
A = LOAD '/user/hduser/salaryTravel.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage. CSVLoader()  AS (name:chararray,job:chararray,salary:chararray,TA:chararray,type:chararray,org:chararray,year:int);
B = foreach A generate name,job,REPLACE(salary,',','') as salary:float, REPLACE(TA,',','') as TA:float, type, org, year;
C = filter B by type=='LBOE';
D = filter C by year==2010;
E = group D by job;
number = foreach E generate group,COUNT(D.salary);
average = foreach E genetate group,AVG(D.salary);
minim = foreach E genetate group,MIN(D.salary);
maxim = foreach E genetate group,MAX(D.salary);
```

Sample Data

```
 (ABBOTT,DEEDEE W,GRADES 9-12 TEACHER,52,122.10,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABBOTT,RYAN V,GRADE 4 TEACHER,56,567.24,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABBOUD,CLAUDIA MORA,GRADES K-5 TEACHER,63,957.50,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABDUL-JABBAR,KHADEEJA ,GRADES 9-12 TEACHER,16,791.73,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABDUL-RAZACQ,SALAHUD-DIN ,INSTRUCTIONAL SPECIALIST P-8,45,832.92,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABDULLAH,DIANA ,SPECIAL ED PARAPRO/AIDE,10,934.94,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABDULLAH,NADIYAH W,GRADES 6-8 TEACHER,75,109.92,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (ABDULLAH,RHONDALYN Y,SPECIAL ED PARAPRO/AIDE,28,649.34,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)
 (OSBORNE,CHRISTINE L,INSTRUCTIONAL SUPERVISOR,78,875.59,3,265.71,LBOE,COBB COUNTY SCHOOL DISTRICT,2010)
 (OSBORNE,DORIS A,OCCUPATIONAL THERAPIST ,65,421.79,1,156.05,LBOE,COBB COUNTY SCHOOL DISTRICT,2010)
```

Sample data after the GROUP operation in line 7.

```
 (GRADE 2 TEACHER,{(OSBORNE,VIRGINIA E,GRADE 2 TEACHER,65587.90,0,LBOE,COBB COUNTY SCHOOL DISTRICT,2010)})
 (GRADE 4 TEACHER,{(ABBOTT,RYAN V,GRADE 4 TEACHER,56567.24,0,LBOE,ATLANTA INDEPENDENT SCHOOL SYSTEM,2010)})
 (MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,{(BROOKS,RICHARD M,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.52,0,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010),(SUMNER,ROBERT O,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.53,0,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010),(MCCULLOUGH,ALVIN J,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.52,0,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010),(DALTON,JAMES E,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.52,2124.60,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010),(SMITH,KEVIN W,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.52,0,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010),(MANGHAM,LARRY G,MAINTENANCE PERSONNEL,72655.52,0,LBOE,FULTON COUNTY BOARD OF EDUCATION,2010)})
```

Is it a bug in Pig? Please help me.

Comment: Can you please post the sample data..How it looks like

Comment: The csv data format and schema defined for loading the data is not matching. The input data you have provided it looks like output of a `group by` command. Please provide the correct data.

Comment: @abhishekbafna Yes. I mean the sample data after group by operation in line 2. It is the sample of 'B' in line 2. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: is the issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated Pig Script.

```
register 'pig/contrib/piggybank/java/piggybank.jar';
define Replace org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE();
A = LOAD '/user/hduser/salaryTravel.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage. CSVLoader()  AS (name:chararray,job:chararray,salary:chararray,TA:chararray,type:chararray,org:chararray,year:int);
B = foreach A generate name,job,REPLACE(salary,',','') as salary, REPLACE(TA,',','') as TA, type, org, year;
B1 = foreach B generate name, job, (double)salary, (double)TA, type, org, year;
C = filter B1 by type=='LBOE';
D = filter C by year==2010;
E = group D by job;
number = foreach E generate group,COUNT(D.salary);
average = foreach E generate group,AVG(D.salary);
minim = foreach E generate group,MIN(D.salary);
maxim = foreach E generate group,MAX(D.salary);
```

The issue was, you need to provide a explicit casting to the `salary` and `TA` attributes.

Comment: Did you get the average,MIN and MAX? Btw, there is no extra field. The name has two parts; first and last name separated by comma. And I can compute the COUNT of A.salary but AVG is not possible. Any idea?

Comment: Yes. Name have two parts. That is why I have put name and lastname two attribute in schema while loading the data. All the operation are working fine. The script I have provide works fine for the sample data which I have extracted from your question.

Comment: OK. That's not working in my case. So I have edited the code in question with some additional lines that does some filter operation and cleaning. Please have a look. In this case too I am able to calculate COUNT.

Comment: can you provide the sample data which you are using so it will be consistent to try it out.

Comment: I have updated the script as yours. You don't need the step-2 from your script. I have removed that. I have also provided the output of `avg` function. If nothing works, then just copy the sample data and script from the answer and run them separately. let me know what happens then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88599/discussion-between-niyas-and-abhishek-bafna).